# python: If an entry is not an acceptable parameter for a prompt, how to re-ask

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Im only comfortable with for loops at the moment so I've tried what I can there with minimal success. If I asked the user if they want A, B, or C and the user inputs D, instead of just saying it is invalid and moving on, i'd like the program to ask again until it gets a valid answer using raw_input.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Damn, this should be available as a template under the "add comment" button.

Comment: Lame, I have tried many different lines of code, but this seems so simple i figured it would be worthless to put my code up. BTW Inbar there are MANY people actually looking for easy answers to complex problems.

Comment: First, this is NOT a complex problem. Secondly, we spent FREE time helping you there, therefor if you don't put a bit of effort in it, we won't bother. There are 1000 people asking things like this out there. We priorize. As simple as that.

Comment: Please let's avoid an argument here, we are all here either to get help or help others, no one here is trying to abuse the system.

Comment: The usual pattern I see for this involves `while` loops. Something like: `valid_selections = set(['A', 'B', C']); user_selection = None; while user_selection not in valid_selections: user_selection = raw_input('Please enter A, B or C')`

Comment: @InbarRose you are a better man that I am ^^

Comment: I believe you misunderstood. This is a very easy problem, and others are asking for easy answers to complex time consuming problems. While I greatly appreciate free advice, I do not appreciate rude comments that seem in contrast to prioritizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an anonymous function that does what you want.

```
def get_user_choice(prompt, choices):
    while True:
        choice = raw_input(prompt)
        if choice in choices:
            return choice
        else:
            print 'choice must be in: {}'.format(choices)
```

Using it:

```
>>> get_user_choice('choose an option in A, B, C: ', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
choose an option in A, B, C: A
'A'
>>> get_user_choice('choose an option in A, B, C: ', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
choose an option in A, B, C: D
choice must be in: ['A', 'B', 'C']
choose an option in A, B, C: B
'B'
```

**Note:** I have not given too much information to help you, because I believe you should figure most of this out on your own, but meanwhile you should have some kind of working solution.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose a better question would have been what loop should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
answers = ['a', 'b','c']

while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Input> ")
    if user_input in answers:
        break

print "'{0}'' has been chosen".format(user_input)
```

Comment: Don't use the word `input` as your variable name, it shadows the builtin `input()` function.

Comment: @InbarRose thanks. didnt think about it