# Python Exit The loop and start the whole process from start once again

Tags: python

I am new to Python Scripting. I have written a code in python. it works pretty fine till now. What I need to know is how can I run it multiple times, I want to start the whole script from start if the condition fails. The sample code is below. This script is saved in file called adhocTest.py  so I run the script like below in python shell

while 1 ==1:
        execfile('adhocTest.py')

The function main() runs properly till the time txt1 == 2 which is received from the user input. Now when the input of txt1 changes to other than 2 it exits the script because I have given sys.exit()   what I need to know is how can I start the the script adhocTest.py once again without exiting if the input of tx1 is not equal to 2. I tried to find the answer but somehow I am not getting the answer I want.

```
  import time
  import sys
  import os

  txt = input("please enter value \n")

  def main():
      txt1 = input("Please enter value only 2 \n")
      if txt1 == 2:
          print txt
          print txt1
          time.sleep(3)
      else:
          sys.exit()  

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      while 1 == 1:
          main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to get user input? if so - you may want to look at [my answer to another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20261433/1561176)

Comment: Thank you @InbarRose   No I will not be getting any user input. This is sample script. Infact I get the values from a Excel sheet So there is no manual intervention until I cancel the loop by pressing ctrl C

Comment: Based on your comments to our proposed solutions, it is obvious to me that you are not including all information in your question. You will not get an answer/solution that will work for you unless you inform us via including information in the question as to what you are trying to do exactly. You can not keep adding requirements and addendums after you receive answers. If your question was not originally clear enough to get a solid and final answer the first time around - it is a sign you need to improve your question or ask a new one, users will not keep checking back to make sure its okay.

Comment: Try to put your code in another script. Plus some logic, of course, to restart that script.

Comment: @InbarRose I will raise a new question. Sorry I couldn't explain the problem properly.

Comment: You should look at other questions which have answers, and have good score to see how to ask a good question.

Comment: @InbarRose I have raised the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428149/python-continue-the-loop-from-start-when-the-condition-is-false">New Question</a>  Forgive me for my coding style as I am still a baby here

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
import time
import sys
import os

def main():
    while True:
        txt = input("please enter value \n")
        txt1 = input("Please enter value only 2 \n")
        if txt1 == 2:
            print txt
            print txt1
            time.sleep(3) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: This solution is not giving me option to enter the value for txt if the condition is false. When the condition is false for txt1, The script should start from the beginning asking value for txt as well

Comment: That is not what your original script writes, but that is easy to amend. - Check the edit.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake, I apologise I gave main() as else result instead of sys.exit()    Infact I should not exit here I should start the whole script from start.

Comment: here in this case I have to enter value of txt everytime. but in my actual code the txt part is realted to copying a file from one place to another, and the main() part is entering few values to this sheet also evaluating few values in it. When the evaluation returns false i will close the file and get the New file by starting the script and repeat the main() function again. Hope I am clear here

Comment: You are not clear, anywhere. Please ask a new question, consult [ASK] and [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192545) to make sure that your new question is clear, concise, and can be answered without follow up comments and additions.

Answer (score 0):

You are only re-calling `main` in your `else`. You could re-factor as follows:

```
def main():
    txt1 = input("Please enter value only 2 \n")
    if txt1 == 2:
        print txt
        print txt1
        time.sleep(3)
    main()
```

Alternatively, just call `main()` (rather than wrapping it in a `while` loop) and move the loop inside. I would also pass `txt` explicitly rather than rely on scoping:

```
def main(txt):
    while True:
        txt1 = input("Please enter value only 2 \n")
        if txt1 == 2:
            print txt
            print txt1
            time.sleep(3)
```

The latter avoids issues with recursion.

Comment: Sorry I edited my code, else statement should exit the main() and start the script from start.

Comment: Then just move everything into the `while` loop in `main()`, as per Inbar Rose's answer. You don't need to actually restart the script.

Comment: You mean to say I should hardcode the value for txt?  but in my actual code the txt part is realted to copying a file from one place to another, and the main() part is entering few values to this sheet also evaluatin few values in it.  Whne the evaluation returns false  i will close the file and get the New file by starting the script from start

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying - it is hard to give tips when your example code is so far from what you're trying to achieve. I was suggesting that rather than having an effectively global variable for `txt`, pass it explicitly to `main()` after it is set. However, the comments you have made elsewhere suggest that your aim is rather different from what your current code is doing.