# Python Continue the loop from start when the condition is false

Tags: python

This is the continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396823/python-exit-the-loop-and-start-the-whole-process-from-start-once-again)  where it was not that clear what I want to do.
Now please find the [Full code here](http://www.filedropper.com/mybasiccode) I know this code is very crude as I am new to programming . I am sure this code can be written in another way more optimally but I am not that experienced.
Now my question is I will be running this code from Python shell.

```
while 1 ==1:
    execfile('adhocTest.py')
```

This code consists of two parts  1. Prerequisite 2. Main program.

The prerequisite is to copy a template Excel file and paste in a directory. Main program is to do some operation and result should be written onto this file and validate few cells. If the condition is true main program will keep continuing else I want that whole script should run again i.e Run pre requisite as well as main program. I am stuc at this point as of now if teh condition is false it exits the whole script.

As I said this code is crude if anyone helps me to optimize it I will be very happy. But this is secondary. I need the continuous run of this script when the condition is false.

Comment: 1 will always equal 1, so how can your condition be `False`?

Comment: Condition is inside the main()  programme.  The while condition 1 ==1 is to continue my loop from outside   when i say condition in main() programme i refer to the function check() which is run by main programme

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-structure your program:

```
def call_me():
    while True:
        prerequisite()
        main_operations()
        if validate():
            main_continuing()
```

or

```
def call_me():
    while True:
        prerequisite()
        while validation():
            main_operations()
```

This will loop around as you need it to.

Comment: I will restructure and let you know

Comment: Will it be possible for you to look at the code? I know it is bit lengthy but if you provide answer according to that it will be really great. As per the above suggestion while Validation()  here which validation should happen?   
FYI: I have not put pre requisite under any function as the result of this is used later on in the main programme. Sorry for being a dumb Programmer

Comment: What I have posted is pseudo code; I am suggesting an overall structure, how you implement is up to you. I don't know what validation you need, but suggest you wrap it in a function that returns True (keep going) or False (loop to next file). If you need something from prerequisite, you could return it from the function.

Comment: Thank you jon,  I will try my best to get the answer. Anyway thanks for your Suggestion, its really helpful